# How to force Mongoid to refresh query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

A background job polls `devices` table in a Mongoid mapped database in a Rails 4.0.2 application like that:

```
while go
  Device.all.each do |device|
    #do something
  end
end
```

I can verify that it load the first set correctly. However, it doesn't refresh the set if new devices are added to the database.

Identity map is off (removed in the current version).

Comment: `Mongoid::QueryCache.enabled = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
Mongoid::QueryCache.enabled = false
```